# Conditional inter-arrival times for Poisson and Renewal Process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, point-processes

> Assume $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ are positive inter-arrival times of a renewal process with pdf $p(x)$, i.e., the $k^\text{th}$ arrivals occurs at $\sum_{i=1}^k X_k$.  What is the pdf of inter arrival times given the $N(t)=n$, i.e., the $n^\text{th}$ arrival occured at time $t$? Show that this PDF converges to the $p(x)$.

For Poisson, I know the conditional arrival times are uniformly distributed in $[0,t]$, but I am looking for conditional *inter-arrival times*. And, the same thing for a renewal process.

This should have been well studied in the literature. Can you point me to the right reference, or show me how to prove this? Giving the answer for Poisson point process would be helpful too.

Comment: The question does not make sense.  "Converges" in what sense?  As $n\rightarrow\infty$?  As $t \rightarrow \infty$?  (And neither one yields the intended result, indeed, you already know it does not work for the Poisson case).  You are conditioning on $N(t)=n$. If you fix $t$ and let $n\rightarrow\infty$ then there are a huge number of arrivals in a fixed time, the inter-arrival spacing goes to zero and the inter-arrival density certainly does _not_ go to $p(x)$. If you fix $n$ and let $t\rightarrow\infty$ the spacing goes to infinity and again the density does _not_ converge to $p(x)$.